# "Notify of" vs. "notify for"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, of-for

Which is correct?

> Please notify me **for** any changes in your address.
>   Please notify me **of** any changes in your address.

Comment: Both are granmatical but they mean different things. What is the intended message? What have found so far in dictionaries etc, and what still confuses you about this?

Comment: I wanted the recipient of my letter to inform me if there are changes in his/her address. I initially wrote "Please notify me FOR any changes in your address." Following these:

1. Give me a ring FOR a talk.
2. Watch out FOR any changes in the schedule. 

but then a friend said that it should be "Please notify me OF any changes in your address."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [OLD:](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/notify)

***notify somebody of something***

> The police must be notified of the date of the demonstration.

The more common usage of the preposition ***of*** after the verb notify is evident also from [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20notified%20of%2Cwas%20notified%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20notified%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20notified%20for%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: that was fast.. thank you very much.. did not know about OLD :)